# Dynamic webpage retrieves data from database slowly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm making a dynamic webpage which retrieves lots of data from a database very frequently, like at least every 3 seconds.

I tested my webpage and database locally by using XAMPP. It works perfectly. However, it turns to be very slow after I upload everything to 000webhost (my free account). My webpage even freezes (I cannot scroll the page, not even doing anything but wait for the data to be transferred.) when retrieving the data.

I used a setTimeout function which called several ajax commands to read data from my database. I have optimised the data capacity already, but the page still freezes. I also tried to disable most of the ajax commands and only left one. When loading, the page freezes just as a blink, but anyhow it still freezes...

Most of my ajax commands are like below which simply retrieves data from my database and updates the related fields on my webpage. Some ajax commands uses $.parseJSON() because I need the whole row from a table.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_balance.php",     
            data: {wherematch: localStorage.login_user},        
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned    
            async:false,            
            success: function(response){

                document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = response;


            }
        });
```

Can anyone provide some suggestions how to solve this issue? Should I pay and get a better account?

Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of how long the database query is taking, an AJAX call should not be freezing your page. It's likely your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: There is really not enough information  given for anyone to help you. You should state things like what are you using for the ajax call, jquery or plain javascript? Which is the slow part? What queries are you running? What is being returned by the ajax? And what is the javascript doing with the returned data? Etc etc...

Comment: Thank you both, please see the updated information.

Comment: Your ajax calls are freezing your browser because you have set `async:false`. If you have to get your data this way it is likely that your entire Javascript code base could use an overhaul. Even so, retrieving 'lots of data' every 3 seconds is not good practice, so probably your server code could use some optimisation too.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have to retrieve data at least every 3 seconds because the database table changes every quickly and my user need to see the changed data instantly. Do you have any suggestions about the server code?

Comment: In the absence of any code, I can't say much about the server side. One obvious optimisation would be to send only the changed data, when it changes. Using Server-sent events would allow the server to send the data, and eliminate the need for polling.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, but I don't have any experience of Server-sent events. I'll go goole for it, but just a quick question: should it be run by something like google cron jobs, so the Server-sent events will keep running?

Answer (score 0):

to have an ajax refreshing every 3 s, your javascript & ajax must be like this:

```
function get_data(){
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_balance.php",     
            data: {wherematch: localStorage.login_user},        
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned            
            success: function(response){
                document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = response;
                setTimeout(get_data(),3000);
            }
        });
}
get_data();
```

Put `setTimeout()` function inside the ajax. You will not get freeze because we don't set `async` as `false`